# Finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm looking for a a finitely generated module with submodules that are not finitely generated. I know about $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$, but I need another example.

Could anyone help me? I'm new in algebra.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a non-Noetherian ring. Such a ring will have
an ideal that is not finitely generated. For an example take
$R=\Bbb Z[X_1,X_2,\ldots]$ a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables.
The ideal generated by all the $X_j$ is not finitely generated.

Over a Noetherian ring, all submodules of finitely generated modules are
finitely generated.